# Is there a method to get all materials from only the "classwork" section, in classroom api?

Tags: python, google-classroom

So far `courses.courseworkmaterial.list` returns every material ever uploaded.
I however do not want anything in the `stream` section rather only from the `classwork` section.

[image]

Irrespective of it being a `courseworkmaterial` or `coursework` , as long it is in the "classwork" section, is it possible to retrieve info about it?

Or is the only way fetching everything and filtering around?

Answer (score 0):

Currently from the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWorkMaterials/list) it is not yet possible to filter or even identify course materials by section such as `stream` or `coursework`, etc.

These are the current definitions for `coursework` and `material` for Classroom API:

[Class CourseWorkMaterial](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWorkMaterials#CourseWorkMaterial)

[Class Material](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/Material)

Comment: welp, that's a bummer. thanks for the info tho

Comment: If this helped you you can consider accepting the answer so we can help other people with the same problem by searching for this particular question.